# How to set value select load page in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

```
// Template
<v-select
  :options="options"
  class="type"
  v-model="type"
  @input="changeType()"
/>

// Script
created() {
  this.type = localStorage.getItem('type')
},
methods: {
  changeType: function () {
    localStorage.setItem("type", this.type);
  }
}
```

When I refresh the page or get back to this page I would like to have the selected option which was previously selected. How can I do that with VueJS?

Comment: You can use storage to set the value before you refresh and then get back the data as soon as the refresh completes.

Comment: Can you tell me more..thanks

Comment: are you using vuetify?

Comment: You need to detect a page refresh or page change first, see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495019/how-to-detect-page-is-refreshed-on-vue then before the page actually refreshed you need to save the data in storage. now when come back to the same page you load the data for that page using storage.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this article : [Vue single page application how to retain state data when page refreshes](https://www.programmersought.com/article/69751748727/)

```
import Vuex from "vuex"
 
Vue.use(Vuex)
 
function storeLocalStore (state) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("userMsg",JSON.stringify(state));
}
 
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        username: "Wang Er",
        schedulename: "title",
        scheduleid: 0,
    },
    mutations: {
        storeUsername (state,name) {
            state.username = name
            storeLocalStore (state)
        },
        storeSchedulename (state,name) {
            state.schedulename = name
            storeLocalStore (state)
        },
        storeScheduleid (state,id) {
            state.scheduleid = Number(id)
            storeLocalStore (state)
        },
    }
```

Then when the page loads, the data is retrieved from localStorage and placed in vuex, so `Wang Er` is atApp.vue of created The following code is written in the hook function:

```
/ / Read the status information in localStorage when the page loads
localStorage.getItem("userMsg") && this.$store.replaceState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userMsg")));

/ / Save the information in vuex to localStorage when the page is refreshed
window.addEventListener("beforeunload",()=>{
    localStorage.setItem("userMsg",JSON.stringify(this.$store.state))
})
```